# Get Mac-Address-Table from HPE Aruba Swtich with plink ssh

Tags: powershell, plink

this is my code:

```
@( 
  ' ', #for "Press any key to continue" 
  'show mac-address'
  ) | plink <ip> -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch 

Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

sometimes i get this output:

```
←[1;13r←[1;1HSession sent command exit status 0
Main session channel closed
All channels closed
```

and sometimes i get this output:

```
Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
FATAL ERROR: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
```

If i write the plink command without Pipe:

```
plink <ip> -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch
```

It works. But i need it automated

Comment: Remove the `,` after `a` unless you want to send the literal string `echo` to the remote session

Comment: then i get a syntax error @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Drop the `echo` nonsense altogether: `@('a','show mac-address') | plink ...`

Comment: So you're now getting the expected output? Sounds like it works :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen nah first i get some mac address entries no i get only: FATAL ERROR: Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection

Comment: What happens if you just fire `plink <ip> -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch n;show mac-address` without any pipeline? If that works, you might get along with a simple join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to have an Aruba switch and found that specifying non-interactive SSH with `-batch`, or commands with `-m`, just causes the switch to disconnect your session like you're seeing. Maybe there's a setting to allow it?

I found this works pretty well, using more of a .net approach due to issues with `Start-Process` redirection. This opens `plink` in a separate process, and sends commands to its stdin:

```
# set up a process with redirection enabled
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
  $psi.FileName               = "plink.exe" #process file
  $psi.UseShellExecute        = $false      #start the process from it's own executable file
  $psi.WorkingDirectory       = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY' # or add to path
  $psi.RedirectStandardInput  = $true       #enable the process to read from our standard input
  $psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true       #enable reading standard output from powershell
  # update these:
  $psi.Arguments = "$IPADDRESS -P 22 -ssh -l admin -pw $PASS"

# launch plink
$plink = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);
sleep 1

# send key presses to plink shell
$plink.StandardInput.AutoFlush = $true
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine() # press return to begin session
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine() # press any key to continue (banner)
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine('show mac-address') # get macs
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine('exit') # exit and confirm logoff
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine('exit') 
$plink.StandardInput.WriteLine('y')

# read output from process
$output = $plink.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

# exit plink
$plink.Close()


# outputs like so (trimmed of banners etc)
$output

MAC Address       Port                            VLAN
----------------- ------------------------------- ----
005056-00000X     15                              1
005056-00000Y     9                               1
005056-00000Z     11                              1
```

You may have to play around with the commands a bit, but I found plink was pretty generous with how quickly input gets thrown at it

I did notice if the plink process is waiting (ssh session still connected), then `ReadToEnd()` will wait **forever**. Maybe it can be replaced with a `ReadLine()` loop, but it can be hard to tell when it's done.

Comment: The `-batch` cannot cause problems. The `-m` indeed can. Other than that, you are doing basically the same what  @Clijsters does.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl nah, plink tries to start or initialize(?) a shell if you feed commands into `-batch`, which causes this (or at least my) switch to boot you with `Session sent command exit status 0 [...] SH command execution is not supported.`, though sometimes the line portion complaining about SH gets eaten if you try to send a list of commands

Comment: I do not really understand your comment. But `-batch` does not have any effect on communication with the server. It affects only how local Plink user prompts are handled.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale your Solution works. But: i get the mac-address-table but with:

[24;1H[2K-- MORE --, next page: Space, next line: Enter, quit: Control-C[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H
[24;1H[2K-- MORE --, next page: Space, next line: Enter, quit: Control-C[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H

Comment: @Cpt.Whale But the Putty window doesnt close it stuck at ReadToEnd. I need to manually close the window

Comment: @Elias ah, I didn't have enough mac addresses for multiple pages - you may have to send some more `WriteLine()` entries after the mac address command. The "next page" prompt is eating the `exit` commands, so powershell can't read to end (because putty is still active). Plink in the windows cmd console just has issues in general with ansi escape characters, so there's not much you can do there (maybe start plink from powershell core like `filename=pwsh.exe` and  `args="-NoExit c:\folder\plink.exe [plink args...]"`

Comment: All this said, I'm pretty sure it's going to be easier to automate using snmp to grab these if you can. A different ssh client like openssh might do better as well

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in your comment (and edited in your question)

```
plink <ip> -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch `n;show mac-address
```

works fine. You could *automate* this by just joining your statements together with [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$ip = "192.168.123.123"
@(
    "\n",
    "show-mac-address",
    "just-another-command"
) | Join-String -Separator ";" | ForEach-Object {
    plink $ip -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch $_
}
```

This basic example simply renders to `plink 192.168.123.123 -P 22 -ssh -v -l admin -pw pwd -batch \n;show-mac-address;just-another-command`.

This happens in two steps: `Join-String` takes your input array from the pipeline and joins it together to one string: `\n;show-mac-address;just-another-command`. This one string is then passed thru the pipeline to ForEach-Object. This cmdlet takes it, sets [PsItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_psitem?view=powershell-7.3) to this Value and executes the plink command one time for every string passed to it (which is in fact only one element)

For older PowerShell-Versions `[string]::Join(";", $statements)` might be of help for you.

Comment: "$_" something is missing there

Comment: No, what are you missing? It's `$_` as its supposed to be. To clarify: Do you know, what that means? Did you hear of PSItem?

Comment: @Elias I just added some explanation.

Comment: Output:

Session sent command exit status 0
Main session channel closed
SAll channels closed
SH command execution is not supported.